# Process substitution into grep missing expected outputs

Tags: bash, pipeline, io-redirection, process-substitution

Let’s say I have a program which outputs:

```
abcd
l33t
1234
```

which I will simulate with `printf 'abcd\nl33t\n1234\n'`. I would like to give this output to two programs at the same time. My idea would be to use process substitution with `tee`. Let’s say I want to give a copy of the output to `grep`:

```
printf 'abcd\nl33t\n1234\n' | tee >(grep '[a-z]' >&2) | grep '[0-9]'
```

I get the following with Bash 4.1.2 (Linux, CentOS 6.5), which is fine:

```
l33t
1234
abcd
l33t
```

But if the process substitution is *not* redirected to stderr (i.e. without `>&2`), like this:

```
printf 'abcd\nl33t\n1234\n' | tee >(grep '[a-z]') | grep '[0-9]'
```

Then I get:

```
l33t
1234
l33t
```

It’s like the stdout from process substitution (the first grep) is used by the process after the pipe (the second grep).  Except the second grep is already reading things by itself, so I guess it's not supposed to take into account things from the first grep. Unless I’m mistaken (which I surely am).

What am I missing?

Comment: @cxw Linux, CentOS 6.5

Comment: Possible workaround: `... | tee >(grep '[a-z]') >(grep '[0-9]') > /dev/null | cat`. The `cat` is needed. Without it, the shell may prompt before both `grep` processes terminate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Explanation

As far as the command line is concerned, [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) is just a way of making a special filename.  (See also the [docs](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html).)  So the second pipeline actually looks like:

```
printf 'abcd\nl33t\n1234\n' | tee /dev/fd/nn | grep '[0-9]'
```

where `nn` is some file-descriptor number.  The full output of `printf` goes to `/dev/fd/nn`, and also goes to the `grep '[0-9]'`.  Therefore, only the numerical values are printed.

As for the process inside the `>()`, it inherits the stdout of its parent.  In this case, that stdout is inside the pipe.  Therefore, the output of `grep '[a-z]'` goes through the pipeline just like the standard output of `tee` does.  As a result, the pipeline as a whole only passes lines that include numbers.

When you write to stderr instead (`>&2`), you are bypassing the last pipeline stage.  Therefore, the output of `grep '[a-z]'` on stderr goes to the terminal.

#### A fix

To fix this without using stderr, you can use another alias for your screen.  E.g.:

```
printf 'abcd\nl33t\n1234\n' | tee >(grep '[a-z]' >/dev/tty ) | grep '[0-9]'
                                               # ^^^^^^^^^
```

which gives me the output

```
l33t
1234
abcd
l33t
```

#### Testing this

To sort this out, I ran `echo >(ps)`.  The `ps` process was a child of the `bash` process running the pipeline.

I also ran

```
printf 'abcd\nl33t\n1234\n' | tee >(grep '[a-z]')
```

without the `| grep '[0-9]'` at the end.  On my system, I see

```
abcd    <--- the output of the tee
l33t         ditto
1234         ditto
abcd    <--  the output of the grep '[a-z]'
l33t         ditto
```

All five lines go into the `grep '[0-9]'`.

Comment: Granted it was discarded, I think it should have written only l33t and 1234 from the `grep '[0-9]'`. But somehow there is a l33t that, I guess, comes from the `grep '[a-z]'`.

Comment: @vdavid OK --- got it!  Thanks for asking; I learned some things. :)  Take a look and let me know what you think.

Comment: That makes sense. I didn’t know stdout was passed to its parent. Thanks for finding that out. I think I just need to play around with file descriptors then, e.g. `exec 3>&1 ; printf 'abcd\nl33t\n1234\n' | tee >(grep '[a-z]' >&3) | grep '[0-9]' 3>&-`

Answer (score 2):

After the `tee` you have two streams of

```
abcd
l33t
1234
```

The 1st grep (`>(grep '[a-z]' >&2`) filters out the

```
abcd
l33t
```

and prints the result to **its**(!!!) stderr - which is still connected to your terminal...

So, another simple demo:

```
printf 'abcd\nl33t\n1234\n' | tee >(grep '[a-z]' >&2) | grep '[0-9]'
```

this prints

```
l33t
1234
abcd
l33t
```

now add the `wc -l`

```
printf 'abcd\nl33t\n1234\n' | tee >(grep '[a-z]' >&2) | grep '[0-9]' | wc -l
```

and you will get

```
abcd
l33t
       2
```

where you clearly can see: the

```
abcd
l33t
```

is the stderr of the 1st `grep` but the 2nd grep's stdout is redirected to the `wc` and prints the

```
2
```

Now another test:

```
printf 'abcd\nl33t\n1234\n' | tee >(grep '[a-z]' ) | cat -
```

output

```
abcd
l33t
1234
abcd
l33t
```

e.g. the two lines from the `grep` and the full input from the `print`

count:

```
printf 'abcd\nl33t\n1234\n' | tee >(grep '[a-z]' ) | cat - | wc -l
```

output

```
5
```

Comment: @cxw's answer and wording is nicer. :) but maybe the `wc` demo helps too in understanding ;)